# Modify ARRAY of STRUCTS in BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an `Array of Structs` in BQ with several fields, what I'm trying to do is traverse the array to modify a property of the array:

This is my current code:

```
DECLARE catalog ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      tableName STRING,
      type STRING,
      age STRING
    >
>;
SET catalog = [
  ('TABLE_ONE', '', '5'),
  ('TABLE_TWO', '', '6'),
  ('TABLE_THREE', '', '1')
];

FOR field in (select * FROM UNNEST(catalog)) DO

  SET catalog.type = CONCAT('TEST',field.age);

END FOR;
```

How can I modify the array to display the following?

```
catalog = [
  ('TABLE_ONE', 'TEST_5', '5'),
  ('TABLE_TWO', 'TEST_6', '6'),
  ('TABLE_THREE', 'TEST_1', '1')
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below.

```sql
SET catalog = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('TEST_' || c.age AS type) FROM UNNEST(catalog) c
);

SELECT catalog;
```

**Query results**

[image]